# Limit the pagination number

Tags: php, pagination

I have many table rows on my database which contain at least 100 or more of them. Therefore, I need to limit the pagination numbers that is displayed on my page.

Somethime like this:

> Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 .. 40 41 Next

Should become this:

> Prev 1 2 .. 6 7 8 9 10 .. 40 41 Next

The code below is what I use to create a basic pagination:

```
<?php
    require 'php/connect.inc.php';
    $per_page = 6;

    $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM users");
    $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

    $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `user_username` FROM `users` LIMIT $start, $per_page");
    while($mysql_fetch_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo '<p>', $mysql_fetch_assoc['user_username'] ,'</p>';
    }

    if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){
        for ($x=1; $x <= $pages; $x++){
            echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: So what is this for? `$per_page = 6;` <--

Comment: @Till Helge, my code retrieves all of the rows and does not limit the page number

Comment: @user2310422 Then think about it and fix it? And when you get stuck you come back here and ask specifically.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I uset $per_page on SELECT `user_username` FROM `users` LIMIT $start, $per_page to retrieve only 6 results depending on the page number.

Comment: @TillHelge I do not know where to start

Comment: Imagine, the person comes to help you with a question. Oh wait... What question? Post the question in the question...

Comment: @user2310422 and that is what it is supposed to do... You want to retrieve 6. and for the start you use pagenumber * per_page

Comment: I get an impression that you're just to to lazy to: 1. formulate your question properly; 2. try to find a solution on your own

Answer (score 0):

It was not easy to get the question but comparing the code and what you want ( Prev 1 2 3 ... 41 42 43 Next ) and readng the comments I hope I can help you.

If I get it right you try to create a navigation like here http://goo.gl/UzD02 (bottom of the site). Your algorithm do it for all of the found pages:

```
if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){
    for ($x=1; $x <= $pages; $x++){
        echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
    }
}
```

if $pages = 20 and $page < page you will always get:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

A possible solution would be this

```
$dots = true;
if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){
    for ($x=1; $x <= $pages; $x++){
        if ($x > $page + 1) {
            $dots = true;
        } 
        if($x > 5 && $dots) {
            echo "...";
            $dots = false;
            if ($x < $page - 1) {$x = $page - 1;}
            elseif ($x < $pages - 3) {$x = $pages - 3;}
        } else {
            echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code but this the part of the code, where you have to look at and imo it should work. The code also could be better.

**EDIT after comment**

For the pagination like google just do it like this:

```
$numberOfPages = 10;
if($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){
    if($pages + $numberOfPages < $pages) {
       $numOfSlectablePages =  $pages + $numberOfPages;
    } else {
       $numOfSlectablePages = $pages;
    }
    for ($x = $page; $x <= $numOfSlectablePages; $x++){
        echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>';
    }
}
```

it's not exactly like google, but I am realy busy right now and i think you get the right direction. If you want it like google just think a little bit about what you have to do or let me know, that you have no idea and I will give an answer on Sunday evening.

Comment: Is this similar to google pagination? Because that's exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Look at the bottom. https://www.google.com/#q=pagination&safe=off&ei=Xzx6Uff0FNXC4APL8oHoCA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6f7c90a3f96d81ca&biw=1440&bih=775

Comment: no the code creats a menu like you discribed: 1 2 3 4 5 ... 22 **23** 24 ... 40 41 42 if I get you right you want the google pagination? Give me a minute.